# How can I get the name of a node?

Tags: yaml-cpp

Is there a way to get the name of a node?  For example:

```
Fruits:
   - apple
   - orange
   - pear
```

and in C++:

```
YAML::Node fruit = parser["Fruits"];
cout << fruit.name() << endl;  // should print "Fruits"
```

is there something like YAML::Node::name()?  I don't see anything in Node.h that fits the bill.

If there isn't, any suggestions on a simple way to modify the code to record this information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you're really looking for is the key associated with a value in a map. You're right, there's no link back from a value to its key, but you can store one, when you're navigating the node in the first place.

If all of your keys are string keys, then whenever you pass a value to some function, just pass along the string key as well:

```
// Instead of:
doSomething(node[key]);

// Call:
doSomething(key, node[key]);
```

Comment: It would be really nice for the parser to have this information embedded in it so that user code didn't have to keep track of the hierarchy for error trapping purposes.

Comment: If the parser doesn't keep this information then I must embed most YAML calls in try/catch blocks with my own error handling or other similarly invasive error trapping.  This adds a lot of overhead to the user code.

Comment: Please file a feature request on the project home page, if you feel like this is important.

Answer (score 0):

```
Fruits:
   - apple
   - orange
   - pear
```

This is one key-value-pair

"Fruits" is the key

" -apple
-orange
-pear " is the value

```
YAML::Node fruit = parser["Fruits"];
```

This command use one key to query the value
So the node "fruit" just keep information about value.